# regex to extract show name, which include the year

Tags: .net, regex

I'm working on a .net program that will use regex to capture the title of a show from a filename, but having trouble when the show name should include a year. Here is what I have so far.

```
(?i)(.*?(?:19\d{2}|20\d{2})(?=[ -]+([\d]|[S][\d]|Season)))
```

The trouble is that this will match The Flash 2014 but not Top Chef. And if I make the (?:19\d{2}|20\d{2}) optional by adding a question mark at the end it will then match Top Chef but not The Flash 2014, it will be missing the year.

Example files:

```
Top Chef S14E14 Comida Final.mkv
The Flash 2014 03x01 720p HDTV X264-DIMENSION.mkv
```

Is my issue related to the optional group being in front of the positive lookahead? How do I fix it so that the query matches both shows?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you mean to differentiate the title from what isn't the title?

Comment: If there is one or more white space or dash followed by a number, S with 2 digits, or the word Season, then everything before it should be considered the title of the show. However the match for a number is thrown off by a year being included.

Answer (score 0):

With the 2 lines you provided, this regex works:

```
^([\w\s]+)(?=\s{2,}|\-\d|s\d{2}|season|\d{4})
```

It matches every sequence of characters, spaces or underscores that are followed by one of the following:

- at least 2 spaces
- a dash and a number
- "s" followed by 2 digits
- "season"
- 4 digits

You should then trim the result to remove the trailing space, if present

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to get it working.

```
^                         # BEGINNING OF STRING

(?<TITLE>                 # CAPTURE THE TITLE
  .+?                     # ANYTHING UP THROUGH (YEAR OR LOOKAHEAD FOR SEASON)
  (?:\s+(?:19|20)\d{2})?  # OPTIONALLY - A SPACE FOLLOWED BY A YEAR
)                         # END OF TITLE CAPTURE

(?=\s+(?:\d|S\d|Season))  # LOOKAHEAD FOR THE SEASON
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/regex/comments/6fepo3/getting_show_title_from_filename/dihlh8a/